# Several errors compiling QField App with Qt Creator

Tags: qgis, qfield, qt

I tried compiling QField on Windows for a week now. But I still have several compiler errors and now I don't know how to fix them. I followed the build manual of the [Github repository](https://github.com/opengisch/QField#for-desktop). So I installed Qt 5.15.2 with Qt Creator. Next I downloaded the latest nightly build qgis-dev with OSGeo4W. In Qt Creator I opened the CMakeLists.txt and added the variables for finding GDAL, QGIS and Proj includes and libs. I use the Desktop Qt 5.15.2 MSVC2019 64 bit kit. With this setting the project configures correctly. When I hit build I get the following errors:
[image]

Is this caused by false Include-Files? Or is it maybe a false compiler?

Do you guys have any tips for me?